# three images when they placed in order looks like triangle in android

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I have three different images like this, orange , green and blue. I have to align them to make a triangle in android.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fl1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bg1"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/a1_home" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fl1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fl2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/bg2"
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="160dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/bg1"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/a2_home" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fl3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/bg3"
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="160dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/a3_home" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then i got spaces between them. the output is like this...
[image]

i want to reduce the spaces in between three images.. i need to make the image like the first one. please help

Comment: don't do like that, please. make a custom view

Comment: i am new to android i don't know how to make a custom view. can you help me...

Comment: it' s not easy I try to explain in a open answer

Comment: can you give this three image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Try giving the FrameLayouts **negative margins** on the inner sides (that is, marginBottom for the top view, marginTop and marginRight for the left view, marginTop and marginRight for the right view). Negative margins will push the views together. Keep adjusting those numbers and testing until you're satisfied.
2. You can also just create a single image containing all three parts and then lay three invsibile Views on top of the ImageView, basically one on top of each part (I assume you need those to make clickable regions).

Answer (score 0):

you must custom a view that's the way:

```
 public class CustomView extends View{

  public CustomView(Context context){
   super(context);
  }  

@Override
private onDraw(Canvas canvas){
  super.onDraw(canvas)
 // now you get canvas to draw whatever you want
 //canvas.drawBitmap() draw a bitmap and place it

 }

}
```